# applying the code on each sheet except few

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code which is working fine with one sheet data i.e on sheet 2, now i wanted to run same code on other worksheet too i.e sheet 4, sheet 5, sheet 6 and sheet 7 to cut the data from these sheet and paste it in sheet 3 as per below codes.

the below code will work as below

I have master Data in Sheet 2 (Column B) and search criteria in Sheet 1 (Column A), i want VBA to find all the data from Sheet 1 (Column A) in Sheet 2 (Column B) if found cut the entire row and past it into Sheet 3 next available row.

i wanted to run same code on other worksheet too i.e sheet 4, sheet 5, sheet 6 and sheet 7 to cut the data from these sheet and paste it in sheet 3 as per below codes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub remDup()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const lName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const lFirst As String = "B1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(lName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = refColumn(sws.Range(lFirst))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = getColumn(srg)
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = refColumn(lws.Range(sFirst))
    If lrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = getColumn(lrg)
    
    ' Match
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(sData)
        If foundMatchInVector(sData(i, 1), lData) Then
            Set trg = getCombinedRange(trg, srg.Cells(i))
        End If
    Next i
            
    ' Destination
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
        ' This is a kind of a ridiculous use of "refColumn".
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
        If drg Is Nothing Then
            Set drg = dws.Range(dFirst).EntireRow
        Else
            Set drg = drg.Cells(drg.Cells.Count).Offset(1).EntireRow
        End If
        trg.EntireRow.Copy drg
        trg.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub

' Assumptions:  'FirstCellRange' is a one-cell range e.g. 'Range("A1")'.
' Returns:      Either the range from 'FirstCellRange' to the bottom-most
'               non-empty cell in the column, or 'Nothing' if all cells
'               below 'FirstCellRange' (incl.) are empty.
Function refColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) _
As Range
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim cel As Range
        Set cel = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not cel Is Nothing Then
            Set refColumn = .Resize(cel.Row - .Row + 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

' Assumptions:  'rg' is a one-column range e.g. 'Range("A1")', 'Range("A1:A2")'.
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column array.
Function getColumn( _
    rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        getColumn = rg.Value
    Else
        Dim OneElement As Variant: ReDim OneElement(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        OneElement(1, 1) = rg.Value
        getColumn = OneElement
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'MatchValue' is a simple data type (not an object or an array).
'               'Vector' is a structure that 'Application.Match' can handle,
'               e.g. a 1D array, a one-column or one-row range or 2D array.
' Returns:      'True' or 'False' (boolean).
' Remarks:      Error values and blanks are ignored ('False').
Function foundMatchInVector( _
    ByVal MatchValue As Variant, _
    ByVal Vector As Variant) _
As Boolean
    If Not IsError(MatchValue) Then
        If Len(MatchValue) > 0 Then
            foundMatchInVector _
                = IsNumeric(Application.Match(MatchValue, Vector, 0))
        End If
    End If
End Function

' Assumptions:  'AddRange' is not 'Nothing' and it is in the same worksheet
'               as 'BuiltRange'.
' Returns:      A range (object).
Function getCombinedRange( _
        ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
        ByVal AddRange As Range)
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set getCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set getCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You could subclass the code into a function which takes a worksheet reference as a variable. You can then have a short sub which calls it for each sheet you want the data stripped from

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to do it, could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

Change the constant to a variable and put the main part of your code in a loop. For example (untested)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub remDup()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    'Const lName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const lFirst As String = "B1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const dFirst As String = "A1"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = refColumn(lws.Range(sFirst))
    If lrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim lData As Variant: lData = getColumn(lrg)
   
    ' Match
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = refColumn(dws.Range(dFirst))
   
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range:
    Dim sData As Variant
    
    Dim lname As Variant
    For Each lname In Array("Sheet2", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7")
    
        ' Source
        Set sws = wb.Worksheets(lname)
        Set srg = refColumn(sws.Range(lFirst))
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
           
            sData = getColumn(srg)
            
            ' Match
            For i = 1 To UBound(sData)
                If foundMatchInVector(sData(i, 1), lData) Then
                    Set trg = getCombinedRange(trg, srg.Cells(i))
                End If
            Next i
                    
            ' Destination
            If Not trg Is Nothing Then
                trg.EntireRow.Copy drg
                trg.EntireRow.Delete
                Set drg = drg.Offset(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```